# IntelliJ Code Iris incomplete

Tags: intellij-idea, class-diagram

I want to use a nice Class Diagram Tool in IntelliJ CE. Code iris looks good to me, but it seems like being incomplete: I have a class `public class Child extends Parent implements SomeInterface`, all 3 in one package. Code iris won't show any connection between these two classes. Any idea why?

To be specific:

```
import ...;
public class PointLight extends Light implements LimitedLight {
    //
}
```

[image]

Comment: Show the snippet please